# How to get details (unit, quantity, price) from XTRF customer invoice API?

Tags: invoice, xtrf

We are using the Customer Invoice Api, but we can'n get the details of the jobs, as unit, quantity and price. Only the "totalAgreed", that is the amount already calculated (quantity * price) of the job. How can we recovery this information?

Project.json and invoice.json do not brint this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Browser API from XTRF. This way, you first create a view within XTRF where all the information is present. Then you execute the Browser API with the Customer Invoice ID as a filter.